# MySQL doesn't respect UNIQUE and PRIMARY-keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates, unique

Hey.
*To start with, I have to say that this is the first time I have ever tried to write SQL, which means I'm a n00b. Have some patience, please..*

Now, I'm trying to create a table called "push" in my database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE push
(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
UDID varchar(40) NOT NULL,
token varchar(64) NOT NULL,
lastpost int DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY(id, UDID, token));
```

That works, but not as expected. If I now try to insert some values here like this:

```
INSERT INTO push (UDID, token, lastpost)
VALUES ('123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz123456789', 211);
INSERT INTO push (UDID, token, lastpost)
VALUES ('123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz123456789', 211);
```

That would, in my eyes, cause an error, because the UDID and token are equal, but it does not trigger any error at all, it just inserts the duplicate.

I might have missed something here, but I can't find out what. How can I make this return the expected result?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this:

```
UNIQUE KEY(id, UDID, token));
```

Means that the combination of those 3 should be unique. The id field (auto-increment) will be different for the 2 rows, so it will satisfy that rule

If the combination should be unique, make it without the `id`

```
UNIQUE KEY(UDID, token));
```

Comment: Don't pass in `id` in the UNIQUE key.

Answer (score 2):

This bit here

```
UNIQUE KEY(id, UDID, token));
```

ensures that you can always enter a duplicate value for UDID, and it will be accepted as the test for uniqeness includes `ID`; which is defined as `auto_increment`. Remove `ID` from this key and you should have the check you want i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE push
(id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
UDID varchar(40) NOT NULL,
token varchar(64) NOT NULL,
lastpost int DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY(id),
UNIQUE KEY(UDID, token)); -- ID now excluded here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both `UDID` and `token` to be unique or in other words no two UDID should be allowed to be the same nor two token should be allowed to be the same, try:

```
CREATE TABLE push
  ( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UDID varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    token varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    lastpost int DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE KEY( UDID ),
    UNIQUE KEY( token )
  ) ;
```